# Making a DrawImage a button in VB.net 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, button, resources, drawimage

I have these three images that I have drawn to my form.

```
    GraphicsBuffer.DrawImage(ButtonEasy, New Rectangle(25, 330, 100, 50), 0, 0, 100, 50, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ImageAttributes)
    GraphicsBuffer.DrawImage(ButtonMedium, New Rectangle(150, 330, 100, 50), 0, 0, 100, 50, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ImageAttributes)
    GraphicsBuffer.DrawImage(ButtonHard, New Rectangle(275, 330, 100, 50), 0, 0, 100, 50, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ImageAttributes)
```

But I want to make a Boolean expression for when they are clicked so I can trigger the events to load the game mode selected.

Do I do this through resource code or is there a simply way to do this. My idea seems like it would be bad and not syntaxically correct.

Edit: I've gotten to this:

```
Private Sub ButtonEasy_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) _
 Handles ButtonEasy.MouseClick

    Dim buttonEasyRect = New Rectangle(25, 330, 100, 50)
    If buttonEasyRect.Contains(e.Location) Then

    End If

End Sub
```

But not really sure where to go from this. Apparently "ButtonEasy.Mouseclick" Handles throws an error "WithEvents variable undefined". Not sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

Edit2: After help from LarsTech I've gotten an Enum in and this:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    Dim level As Difficulty = Difficulty.None
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
    End If

    If New Rectangle(25, 330, 100, 50).Contains(e.Location) Then
        level = Difficulty.Easy
    ElseIf New Rectangle(150, 330, 100, 50).Contains(e.Location) Then       
        level = Difficulty.Medium
    ElseIf New Rectangle(275, 330, 100, 50).Contains(e.Location) Then
        level = Difficulty.Hard
    End If

    If level = Difficulty.Easy Then
        GameMode = 1
    ElseIf level = Difficulty.Medium Then
        GameMode = 2
    ElseIf level = Difficulty.Hard Then
        GameMode = 3
    End If

End Sub
```

How do I call this in my loop? Currently I have the loop wait for Asynchkeypress to set timescale to 300 which starts the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't actually use Buttons to do this?

In any case, you probably should have a class for all that information, which image, which rectangle, etc.  This button class would also hold the IsPushed logic.

But for what you currently have, having an enum would probably help:

```
Public Enum Difficulty
  None
  Easy
  Medium
  Hard
End Enum
```

Then in the MouseDown event:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
  Dim level As Difficulty = Difficulty.None

  If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
    If New Rectangle(25, 330, 100, 50).Contains(e.Location) Then
      level = Difficulty.Easy
    ElseIf New Rectangle(150, 330, 100, 50).Contains(e.Location) Then
      level = Difficulty.Medium
    ElseIf New Rectangle(275, 330, 100, 50).Contains(e.Location) Then
      level = Difficulty.Hard
    End If
  End If

  If level <> Difficulty.None Then
    MessageBox.Show("You are playing " & level.ToString)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for! I'm going to fix it up a bit to fit my code better and I'll come back in a few minutes with the results.

Comment: Ok, I added the new code to my post, just not sure how to call it in my loop.

Comment: @user1041950 You're not making this easy.  What do you mean by loop?  WinForms uses events.  If you click on the form and you are handling the mousedown event, the code that is in my example will run.  You don't need a separate "GameMode" variable, just move the level variable to the class level.

Comment: Ok, what I was doing before was making a loop to prepare the game to launch, and I know I probably could have done it better but its probably too late. How do I make the event on the mousedown only work when call "choosegamemode" is up, handle the mousedown event in that sub?

Comment: @user1041950 It "sounds" like you have one form trying to handle all of these different "views" of the game.  That's not the easiest way to do things in WinForms.  But yes, you should have another enum for GameView, for Setup or Play, and you paint and handle mouse events based on which view you are in.  Am I close to understanding this?

Comment: I believe so, I'm only about a month or so into programming so my understanding of proper syntax and the way to build programs is lacking. What I have built is a form, with a screen buffer drawn to it. I have a loop which checks a timescale to see what should be displayed (title menu, choose game mode, game playing). What you are saying is that I have should have completely different forms for each selection screen and have the program call and swap depending on actions done? I think I am begining to understand although I am probably too committed to my way to change it now...

Comment: @user1041950 You don't need a timer loop unless you are moving your sprites around the form.  For the original question, you just need a variable to determine which "view" the form should be showing at that moment and call Invalidate() to tell the form or control to paint itself and in the paint event, you determine what should be displayed.

Comment: I have moving sprites with many animations as well as collision detection. I guess to sum up my current problem, I have the code from earlier and it is slightly warped to fit what I need, but im not entirely sure how to implement it. If you want, I could send you the relevent code so maybe you could get a better idea of what I'm doing.

Comment: @user1041950 Stack Overflow is good at finding an answer to a well formed question and then hopefully having that answer help the next person.  Sending me the code wouldn't help the internet.  Focus on the immediate task at hand and try to ask questions where you get stuck.  Questions about how to do your entire program aren't a good fit here.  BTW, WinForms is not the best programming environment for sprite-like games (as you are probably finding out).  Good luck.

Comment: Oh well, I guess that this problem just showed a bigger problem. Thanks for all the help.